# replace certain values in df according to several conditions

Tags: r, database, merge

basic question but I am looking for a nice solution (not for loops) for conditional replacement in DF1 by values of DF2 IF several conditions are fulfilled:

```
DF1
Name  Year   Val1
A    2010     x1
A    2012     x2
B    2012     x3
C    2015     x4
C    2012     x5
```

```
DF2
Name  Year   Val1
A    2012     y1
B    2012     y2
C    2012     y3
```

If Year is of a certain value such as 2012 in this case and the Name of DF1 and DF2 are the same then assign Val1 from DF2 to DF1.

I tried several things:
`DF1$Val1[DF1$Year=="2012"&DF1$Name==DF2$Name,] <-DF2$Val1`
`DF1$Val1<-replace(DF1$Val1, DF1$Year=="2012" & DF1$Name==DF2$Name, DF2$Val1)`

But I unfortunately get an error because DF1 and DF2 are not of the same length.

Expected:

```
DF1
Name  Year   Val1
A    2010     x1
A    2012     y1
B    2012     y2
C    2015     x4
C    2012     y3
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: sorry totally forget that! I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a join `on` the columns with `data.table` and update the 'Val'

```
librar(data.table)
setDT(DF1)[DF2, Val1 := i.Val1, on = .(Name, Year)]
DF1
#   Name Year Val1
#1:    A 2010   x1
#2:    A 2012   y1
#3:    B 2012   y2
#4:    C 2015   x4
#5:    C 2012   y3
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), Year = c(2010L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2015L, 2012L), Val1 = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 
"x5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 
2012L), Val1 = c("y1", "y2", "y3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This omits all values of DF1 if they are in DF2 even if NA. If Val1 from DF2 is NA I dont want to join this into my new DF

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to filter DF2 down and then append it to DF1.

So

```
    DF2 <- dplyr::filter(DF2, Year==2012,
                     Name %in% unique(DF1$Name)
    DF1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(DF1, DF2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two base R solutions.

*- Using `match`:*

```
inds <- match(data.frame(t(DF2[-3]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              data.frame(t(DF1[-3]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
DF1$Val1[inds] <- DF2$Val1
```

such that

```
> DF1
  Name Year Val1
1    A 2010   x1
2    A 2012   y1
3    B 2012   y2
4    C 2015   x4
5    C 2012   y3
```

*- Using `merge` + `subset`:*

```
DF1 <- subset(within(merge(DF1,DF2,by=c("Name","Year"),all.x = TRUE), 
                     Val1 <- ifelse(is.na(Val1.y),Val1.x,Val1.y)),
              select = names(DF1))
```

such that

```
> DF1
  Name Year Val1
1    A 2010   x1
2    A 2012   y1
3    B 2012   y2
4    C 2012   y3
5    C 2015   x4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `left_join` `df1` and `df2` on `Name` and `Year` and use `coalesce` to select non-NA values from the two `Val1` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = c('Name', 'Year')) %>%
  mutate(Val1 = coalesce(Val1.y, Val1.x)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

#  Name Year Val1
#1    A 2010   x1
#2    A 2012   y1
#3    B 2012   y2
#4    C 2015   x4
#5    C 2012   y3
```

Comment: Does this mean, if Val1 in DF1 is NA it will be replaced by Val1 from DF2, otherwise it will not be replaced?

Comment: @antonina No, this gives preference to `DF2` in the current code now, if `Val1` is present in `DF2` it will take it's value or take `Val1` from `DF1`. This can also be changed if needed by changing the argument in `coalesce` to `coalesce(Val1.x, Val1.y)` to give preference to `DF1`.